# Substitute all occurrences within a specific context using Python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Using Python 3.7, how can I substitute all occurrences of a regex within a string, but only if the occurrence is within a specific context?

For example, how do I replace all instances of `foo` with `bar`, but only if `foo` is inside curly braces?

Input:

```
{foo foo} foo {foofoo} foo foo
```

Output:

```
{bar bar} foo {barbar} foo foo
```

I've tried many things using `re.sub()`, including using lookarounds, but couldn't get to something that works perfectly.

For example, I tried using captured groups to deconstruct and reconstruct the regex:

```py
re.sub(
    r"(?P<delimiter>{)(?P<before_foo>.*)(?P<foo>foo)(?P<after_foo>.*)(?P<end_delimiter>})",
    r"\g<delimiter>\g<before_foo>bar\g<after_foo>\g<end_delimiter>",
    input
)
```

This would only do the substitution within the curly braces but would fail if there's more than one `foo` in the string.

I also tried using lookarounds:

```py
re.sub(r"foo(?!.*{)(?=.*})", bar, input)
```

This works well as long as there is just one pair of curly braces in the string, so for the input `{foo foo} foo` it would correctly output `{bar bar} foo`, but for the input `{foo foo} foo {foofoo} foo foo` it would incorrectly output `{foo foo} foo {barbar} foo foo`.

Comment: What's your expected output for `{food}`? `{bard}` or `{food}`?

Comment: Or even `{foobar}`

Comment: @anubhava, I've tried many things, none of which were good enough to share. I don't want to confuse future readers with ideas in the wrong direction.

Regarding `{food}` - I expect `{bard}`. For `{foobar}` I expect `{barbar}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
inp = "{foo foo} foo {foofoo} foo foo"
output = re.sub(r'\{(.*?)\}', lambda x: '{' + x.group(1).replace('foo', 'bar') + '}', inp)
print(input)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
{foo foo} foo {foofoo} foo foo
{bar bar} foo {barbar} foo foo
```

The strategy used here is to match all contents `{...}` inside curly braces.  This content is then passed to a callback function which selectively replaces `foo` with `bar`.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know you can pass in a lambda for a regex match!